# Apple Maps developer: pricing?

Tags: ios

I am wondering if there are any costs of usage of Maps for the apps? I am talking about more users, so about 20,000+ map refreshes per day. I couldn't find it anywhere in the web, but I know google maps do have a pricing model.

Thanks
uksz

Comment: Do you mean iOS native Maps application?

Comment: Yeah, exactly! I will fix that, because it's missleading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find anything official, but I hope this helps:

> Apple has no limits on access to their location search API

[Source](http://www.fastcompany.com/3006725/open-company/depth-comparison-between-ios-map-frameworks-apple-mapkit-vs-google-maps-sdk%20[Source])

Comment: I found this article as well. However, I couldn't find anything in their developer portal.. :( I guess if no other user will provide any other info, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: I think anything that Apple provides as part of the SDK is free to use, except the fees (30%) from InAppPurchases when you make a sale.

Comment: Alright. That makes sense, both from developer point of view, and their business model :)

Answer (score 7):

According to [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW7) it's no limits, as long as the app is well-written.

> There are no request limits per app or developer ID, so well-written apps that operate correctly should experience no problems. However, throttling may occur in a poorly written app that creates an extremely large number of requests.

Comment: I think it refers to 'Directions requests made using the `MKDirections`' - but it's still a more credible source than mine ))

Comment: I think so too, but it was the only thing I found that had something to do with request limits.Weird that Apple aren't letting everyone know if there is no limit at all since Google has a limit and then you have to pay. Thought these two companies was competitors :)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for that information once and what I found out that there are no limit for geocoding, however it is reasonable to rethink the way you send requests to make them as few as possible.

Apple says:

> Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
>
> When you want to update the user’s current location automatically (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute.

Comment: It's vague and seems to be up to their discretion. I tested the limits a year or so ago and found that they'd start throttling me to about 1 per minute on average within a ~5 minute window.

Answer (score 1):

***Web:*** Per Apple Developer Program membership You have daily limit 250 000 of map views,

***Mobile***: no additional cost beyond your Apple Developer Program if you are using native MapKit

Comment: Can you add some references? As you can see, this information is not written explicitly (or it's not easy to find, in any case), which is crucial information when developing a commercial app.

Comment: I get this information from apple support. I don't have any link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apple map tiles with a web app.

From the [Apple MapkitJS](https://developer.apple.com/maps/web/) documentation (bottom of page).

> MapKit JS beta provides a free daily limit of 250,000 map views and 25,000 service calls per Apple Developer Program membership. For additional capacity needs, contact us.

So, approx 7 million map views per month. It mentions beta though, so It may change once out of beta.